# Convert object to datetime stamp in python pandas. Where day has no leading zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I cant seem to convert this dataframe column to a datetime stamp.

Date_Last_Modified
January 1 2021 7:36:32 pm
January 11 2021 7:36:32 pm... ect

The dtype is an object and the %e does not work nor does the %-d work.  this is my command.

`df['Date_Last_Modified'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Last_Modified'], format='%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p')`

Here is the error

`ValueError: time data 'Date Last Modified' does not match format '%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p' (match)`

or

`df['Date_Last_Modified'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Last_Modified'], format='%B %e %Y %I:%M:%S %p')`

`ValueError: 'e' is a bad directive in format '%B %e %Y %I:%M:%S %p'`

Comment: For me working well, is possible check if some bad values by `print (df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Last_Modified'], format='%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce').isna()])` ?

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the reply.  I ran your code and it returned a dataframe that looked like this.  I know there are no N/A in the column. I am running linux xubuntu.                    
.......................Date_Last_Modified...........................................................................                                     
20 Date Last Modified

Comment: So there is `20` between values like `January 1 2021 7:36:32 pm` ?

Comment: yes when i ran your code, the number it outputed was 20... sorry i cant make a dataframe in the comments.  the data frame has 137 rows, some of the times are duplicates.

Comment: So there was some bad values? `print (df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Last_Modified'], format='%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce').isna()])` is for test them - because `errors='coerce'` create misisng values for no parseable strings.

Comment: As error message said, there is an error value `Date Last Modified` in your 'Date_Last_Modified' column. you need to remove that value.

Comment: there was an error on line 20, (21 in the csv) as i did not use the drop duplicates properly for the duplicated headers and i kept the first instance of the header names that was row 20.  It is working now, thank you!

Comment: I tested it incorrectly, you are right. I fixed the correct solution pointing to the comment here.  I can accept the answer and close the question in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want test what values are wrong add `errors='coerce'` and test missing values:

```
print (df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Last_Modified'], 
                         format='%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p', 
                         errors='coerce').isna()])
```

Here is simplier solution - first converted bad values to `NaN`s by parameter `errors='coerce'` and then using [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) remove this rows:

```
df['Date_Last_Modified'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Last_Modified'], 
                                           format='%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p', 
                                           errors='coerce')

df = df.dropna(subset=['Date_Last_Modified'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter error values in the column 'Date_Last_Modified' as the following:

```
FMT = '%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p'
col = 'Date_Last_Modified'
errors_values = (df[pd.to_datetime(df[col], format=FMT, errors='coerce').isna()]).values
df = df[~df[col].apply(lambda x: x in errors_values)]
```

after this, you should not have the same error.

```
df['Date_Last_Modified'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Last_Modified'], format='%B %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```